# Separator line appear early than cell title and image goes beyond of UIImageView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I programmatically created UITableView and Cell. All work good, but I have a couple questions about constraints and auto layout:

Constraints with layoutMarginsGuide:

1. In screens where width 375, lower separator and cell starts from one point. On big size screens, separator appears earlier than the cell title(you can see this in attached screenshot). How I can fix this?
2. The image of the red rectangle with round corners in the attached screenshot goes beyond of UIImageView. I added constraints to UIImageView, but this not help me. How I can fix this?

Constraints without layoutMarginsGuide:

1. I want that stackView to cover the whole cell. How can I add constraints without using layoutMarginsGuide and avoid console warnings?
2. How can I add height constraints? I want that my stackView or title was 100 pt.

Screenshot, cell icon, and code you can found below.

Thanks for your answer.

[Rectangle with rounded corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5fUQ.png)

Screenshot:
[image]

**Code:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let tableViewstyle = UITableView.Style.insetGrouped
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(), style: tableViewstyle)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(Cell1.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(Cell1.description()))
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor),
            tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    // MARK: - numberOfSections
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    // MARK: - numberOfRowsInSection
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }
    
    // MARK: - cellForRowAt
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(Cell1.description())) as! Cell1
        cell.title.text = "Cell \(indexPath.row)"
        cell.icon2.image = UIImage(named: "Icon")
        
        return cell
    }
  
}

// MARK: - Cell
class Cell1: UITableViewCell {
        
    // MARK: - Properties
    let title = UILabel()
    let icon2 = UIImageView()
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        // Off translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints
        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        icon2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // Set constraints
        icon2.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: icon2, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30))
        icon2.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: icon2, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30))
        
        // StackView
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        
        // TitleAndDetailStackView
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        
        // Hugging
        title.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750), for: .horizontal)
        
        // Resistance
        title.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750), for: .horizontal)
        icon2.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250), for: .horizontal)
        
        title.textAlignment = .left
        title.numberOfLines = 0
        
        // Highlight stackView and set colors
        stackView.addBackground(color: .green)
        title.textColor = .label
        icon2.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        // Add title and detail
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(title)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(icon2)
        
        icon2.contentMode = .center
        
        // Add to subview
        self.contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        // Get layoutMarginsGuide
        let layoutMarginsGuide = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        // Set constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // Constrain all 4 sides of the stack view to the content view's layoutMarginsGuide
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        ])
                
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}

// MARK: - AddBackground
extension UIStackView {
    func addBackground(color: UIColor) {
        let subView = UIView(frame: bounds)
        subView.backgroundColor = color
        subView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        insertSubview(subView, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To achieve this we need to change constraints to `contentView.` and set `leadingAnchor.constraint` constant equal to `16.0`.

   ```
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
       stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
       stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
       stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
   ])
   ```
2. Change `icon2.contentMode = .center` to `icon2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`
3. StackView that cover the whole cell:

   ```
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
    ])
   ```
4. To change cell height we can simply add height constraint to any object inside the cell:

   `title.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: title, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100))`